# I have an issue in using ${resource(dir:' dir', file:'file.png')} in grails 2.0.0

Tags: grails

I use

```
 <img src="${resource(dir:'images', file:'logo.gif')}" width="249" height="31" />
```

and i got

```
 <img alt="Grails" src="/amwccms/static/cXmUZIAv28XIiNgkRiz4RRl21TsGZ5HoGpZw1UITNyV.png">
```

instead of

```
<img src="/amwccms/images/logo.png">
```

Comment: Do you have resources plugin installed ? Seems to be related to that

Answer (score 1):

The hash used as the resource file name indicates that you may be using the [Grails cached resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cached-resources).
This plugin provides a "hash and cache" mapper for the resources framework, automatically creating safe unique filenames for your resources and setting them to eternally cache in the browser.